# Wp Cron and Wordpress Updates

Tags: wp-cron

If I disable wp-cron from config, will automatic updates still work?

In one of my sites I need to disable wp-cron as its causing high CPU usage but of course I wouldn't want to disable automatic updates.

Any suggestions (such as using a crontab/cronjob) would be apprecaited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I disable wp-cron from config, will automatic updates still work?

No, neither will scheduled posts, transient cleanup, trash clearing after 30 days, or automatic plugin updates, and some other things. Anything that relies on timed or scheduled activities will break.

It seems you already know the solution, though the real solution is to identify which cron jobs are using so much CPU and fix those. Changing how cron runs from WP Cron to a crontab will give limited relief.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, will research further how to get more surgical to identify the culprit. Any further tips always welcome. Thanks